# What api is google maps using for the search box?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

What's the api behind the google maps search box? Is there server side API from google services which third party can use?

Thanks

Comment: The Search box is part of the Places API

Comment: Which API is that? I want to use it server side.

Comment: The Places API is the Places API. It is available as a web service.

Comment: Well, i use "textsearch" from the places api and it doesn't return the same results as the google maps search box. If it is the same, why is that difference?

Comment: If you are asking about the "seach box" on http://maps.google.com, not the Google Maps Javascript API v3 [SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox), then the answer is there is no API that exposes that complete functionality.  It is a combination of the Geocoding API, the Places API and other proprietary Google search results.

Comment: Yes, i'm referring to maps.google.com search box... So, i can't completely get the same search results used in the Google Maps search box?
Thanks confirming this. If you answer below, i will give you reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "seach box" on http://maps.google.com (not the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#places_searchbox)), there is no API that exposes that complete functionality. It is a combination of the Geocoding API, the Places API and other proprietary Google search results